# Where do you think you are going VS Where do you think is the best place?

Tags: grammar

> Where do you think you are going?
>
> Where do you think is the best place?

Why are the word orders in the main clauses different while they are both the same "Where + do you think + main clause"-structure? In other words, why

> Where do you think are you going?
>
> Where do you think the best place is?

are wrong?

Comment: @JasonBassford Could you elaborate it more please? I saw some other places that some of them said "Where do you think are you going" actually wrong.

Comment: My apologies. I had not paid close enough attention to the third sentence, which is indeed wrong. The others are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the syntactic role of the entity which *where* represents.

In the first sentence, *where* represents a locative complement of the verb *GO*. Recast the question as an assertion, replacing *where* with *there*, and the sentence would be

> *You think | you are going **there***.

In the second sentence, *where* represents the subject of the verb *BE*. The assertion version would be

> *You think | **there** is the best place.*

Turn these back into questions—remove the *there*s and put the interrogative at the front, with auxiliary inversion and do-support—and you end up with the correct versions of your sentences.

Comment: I thought "where you are going" is ***almost*** always an ungrammatical interrogative form, though making a perfect subordinate clause. Are you talking about changing the intonation when reading the statement out loud? I mean turning a usual declarative statement into an interrogative one using rising intonation?

Comment: @Cardinal But in your sentence you don't ask "Where are you going?"--you "Where do you **think** you are going?" We only invert with do-support once, in the main clause.

Comment: I don't think _where_ is the subject. I'd only say _Where are the best places to live in NY?_, not _Where is the best places to live in NY?_.

Comment: @JK2 But OP asks "Where do you think is the best place?", singular.

Comment: @StoneyBonhiatus Yes, but the plural sentences are a test to disprove that "where" is "the subject of the verb _BE_".